# cron observer vs controller action memory issue

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, controllers

In my custom module i've got an observer for cron schedule and a frontend action controller to test.

Controller action and observer function are the same but when the script run from the observer by cron schedule i've got this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 5200001 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 290
```

this doesn't happen from controller action.

cron.php is launched by:

```
/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php -c /var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/etc/php.ini
```

site web runs in:

```
/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php-cgi -c /var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/etc/php.ini
```

Any idea?

EDIT:

controller action (works):

```
public function indexAction() {
    $marketPlaces = array(
                    'it' => 'APJ6JRA9NG5V4',
                    'en' => 'A1F83G8C2ARO7P',
                    'fr' => 'A13V1IB3VIYZZH',
                    'de' => 'A1PA6795UKMFR9',
                    'es' => 'A1RKKUPIHCS9HS'
                    );
    $feeds = Mage::getModel('amazon/feed')->getFeeds();
    $count = count($feeds);
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($feeds as $mp => $feedFiles){
        if ($mp != 'delete'){
            foreach ($feedFiles as $feed){
                $responses[] = Mage::getModel('amazon/api')->submitFeed($feed,array($marketPlaces[$mp]));
                if ($i == 15){
                    $count -= $i;
                    if ($count > 15) {
                        sleep(1800);
                    } else {
                        sleep($count * 2 * 60);
                    }
                    $i = 0;
                }
                $i++;
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($feedFiles as $feed){
                foreach($marketPlaces as $marketPlace){
                    $responses[] = Mage::getModel('amazon/api')->submitFeed($feed,array($marketPlace));
                    if ($i == 15){
                        $count -= $i;
                        if ($count > 15) {
                            sleep(1800);
                        } else {
                            sleep($count * 2 * 60);
                        }
                        $i = 0;
                    }
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    foreach ($responses as $response){
        $responseObj = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
        $feedSubmissionIds[] = (string) $responseObj->SubmitFeedResult->FeedSubmissionInfo->FeedSubmissionId;
    }
    if (!file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('var').'/amazon/responses')) {
        mkdir(Mage::getBaseDir('var').'/amazon/responses', 0755, true);
    }
    Mage::getModel('amazon/feed')->deleteAllFiles(Mage::getBaseDir('var').'/amazon/responses');
    $fsiSerialized = serialize($feedSubmissionIds);
    file_put_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('var').'/amazon/responses/responses.txt',$fsiSerialized);
}
```

observer function (gives error):

```
    public function submitFeed(){
    $marketPlaces = array(
                    'it' => 'APJ6JRA9NG5V4',
                    'en' => 'A1F83G8C2ARO7P',
                    'fr' => 'A13V1IB3VIYZZH',
                    'de' => 'A1PA6795UKMFR9',
                    'es' => 'A1RKKUPIHCS9HS'
                    );
    $feeds = Mage::getModel('amazon/feed')->getFeeds();
    $count = count($feeds);
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($feeds as $mp => $feedFiles){
        if ($mp != 'delete'){
            foreach ($feedFiles as $feed){
                $responses[] = Mage::getModel('amazon/api')->submitFeed($feed,array($marketPlaces[$mp]));
                if ($i == 15){
                    $count -= $i;
                    if ($count > 15) {
                        sleep(1800);
                    } else {
                        sleep($count * 2 * 60);
                    }
                    $i = 0;
                }
                $i++;
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($feedFiles as $feed){
                foreach($marketPlaces as $marketPlace){
                    $responses[] = Mage::getModel('amazon/api')->submitFeed($feed,array($marketPlace));
                    if ($i == 15){
                        $count -= $i;
                        if ($count > 15) {
                            sleep(15*2*60);
                        } else {
                            sleep($count * 2 * 60);
                        }
                        $i = 0;
                    }
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    foreach ($responses as $response){
        $responseObj = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
        $feedSubmissionIds[] = (string) $responseObj->SubmitFeedResult->FeedSubmissionInfo->FeedSubmissionId;
    }
    if (!file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('var').'/amazon/responses')) {
        mkdir(Mage::getBaseDir('var').'/amazon/responses', 0755, true);
    }
    Mage::getModel('amazon/feed')->deleteAllFiles(Mage::getBaseDir('var').'/amazon/responses');
    $fsiSerialized = serialize($feedSubmissionIds);
    file_put_contents(Mage::getBaseDir('var').'/amazon/responses/responses.txt',$fsiSerialized);
}
```

EDIT 2:

i've tested memory usage in the loop:

```
2018-03-02T00:00:23+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 18MB
2018-03-02T00:00:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 22MB
2018-03-02T00:00:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 22MB
2018-03-02T00:00:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 22MB
2018-03-02T00:00:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 22MB
2018-03-02T00:00:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 22MB
2018-03-02T00:00:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 22MB
2018-03-02T00:00:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 22MB
2018-03-02T00:00:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 22MB
2018-03-02T00:00:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 22MB
2018-03-02T00:00:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 22MB
2018-03-02T00:00:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 23MB
2018-03-02T00:00:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 23MB
2018-03-02T00:00:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 23MB
2018-03-02T00:00:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 23MB
2018-03-02T00:00:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 23MB
2018-03-02T00:00:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 23MB
2018-03-02T00:00:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 23MB
2018-03-02T00:00:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 23MB
2018-03-02T00:00:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 23MB
2018-03-02T00:00:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 23MB
2018-03-02T00:00:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 23MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 23MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 23MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 23MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 23MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 23MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 23MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 23MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 23MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 23MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 23MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 23MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 24MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 24MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 24MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 24MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 24MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 24MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 24MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 24MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 24MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 24MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 24MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 24MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 24MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 24MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 24MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 24MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 24MB
2018-03-02T00:00:25+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 24MB
2018-03-02T00:00:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 24MB
2018-03-02T00:00:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 25MB
2018-03-02T00:00:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 25MB
2018-03-02T00:00:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 25MB
2018-03-02T00:00:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 25MB
2018-03-02T00:00:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 26MB
2018-03-02T00:00:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 26MB
2018-03-02T00:00:27+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 28MB
2018-03-02T00:00:27+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 28MB
2018-03-02T00:00:27+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 28MB
2018-03-02T00:00:27+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 29MB
2018-03-02T00:00:28+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 29MB
2018-03-02T00:00:28+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 30MB
2018-03-02T00:00:28+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 30MB
2018-03-02T00:00:28+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 30MB
2018-03-02T00:00:28+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 31MB
2018-03-02T00:00:29+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 32MB
2018-03-02T00:00:29+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 33MB
2018-03-02T00:00:29+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 33MB
2018-03-02T00:00:30+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 34MB
2018-03-02T00:00:30+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 34MB
2018-03-02T00:00:30+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 35MB
2018-03-02T00:00:30+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 36MB
2018-03-02T00:00:30+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 37MB
2018-03-02T00:00:31+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 39MB
2018-03-02T00:00:31+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 40MB
2018-03-02T00:00:31+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 42MB
2018-03-02T00:00:31+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 42MB
2018-03-02T00:00:31+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 43MB
2018-03-02T00:00:31+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 43MB
2018-03-02T00:00:31+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 43MB
2018-03-02T00:00:32+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 43MB
2018-03-02T00:00:32+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 44MB
2018-03-02T00:00:32+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 44MB
2018-03-02T00:00:32+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 44MB
2018-03-02T00:00:32+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 45MB
2018-03-02T00:00:32+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 45MB
2018-03-02T00:00:32+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 45MB
2018-03-02T00:00:32+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 46MB
2018-03-02T00:00:32+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 46MB
2018-03-02T00:00:32+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 46MB
2018-03-02T00:00:32+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 47MB
2018-03-02T00:00:32+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 47MB
2018-03-02T00:00:32+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 47MB
2018-03-02T00:00:32+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 48MB
2018-03-02T00:00:32+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 48MB
2018-03-02T00:00:32+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 48MB
2018-03-02T00:00:33+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 48MB
2018-03-02T00:00:33+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 49MB
2018-03-02T00:00:33+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 49MB
2018-03-02T00:00:33+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 49MB
2018-03-02T00:00:33+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 50MB
2018-03-02T00:00:33+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 50MB
2018-03-02T00:00:33+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 50MB
2018-03-02T00:00:33+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 51MB
2018-03-02T00:00:33+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 51MB
2018-03-02T00:00:33+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 51MB
2018-03-02T00:00:34+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 51MB
2018-03-02T00:00:34+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 52MB
2018-03-02T00:00:34+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 52MB
2018-03-02T00:00:34+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 52MB
2018-03-02T00:00:34+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 53MB
2018-03-02T00:00:34+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 53MB
2018-03-02T00:00:34+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 53MB
2018-03-02T00:00:34+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 54MB
2018-03-02T00:00:34+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 54MB
2018-03-02T00:00:34+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 49MB
2018-03-02T00:00:34+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 49MB
2018-03-02T00:00:34+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 49MB
2018-03-02T00:00:34+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 50MB
2018-03-02T00:00:34+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 50MB
2018-03-02T00:00:35+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 51MB
2018-03-02T00:00:35+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 52MB
2018-03-02T00:00:35+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 53MB
2018-03-02T00:00:35+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 54MB
2018-03-02T00:00:35+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 55MB
2018-03-02T00:00:36+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 55MB
2018-03-02T00:00:36+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 56MB
2018-03-02T00:00:36+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 57MB
2018-03-02T00:00:37+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 58MB
2018-03-02T00:00:37+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 59MB
2018-03-02T00:00:37+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 60MB
2018-03-02T00:00:37+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 61MB
2018-03-02T00:00:37+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 61MB
2018-03-02T00:00:37+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 62MB
2018-03-02T00:00:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 62MB
2018-03-02T00:00:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 63MB
2018-03-02T00:00:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 63MB
2018-03-02T00:00:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 63MB
2018-03-02T00:00:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 63MB
2018-03-02T00:00:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 63MB
2018-03-02T00:00:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 63MB
2018-03-02T00:00:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 63MB
2018-03-02T00:00:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 63MB
2018-03-02T00:00:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 63MB
2018-03-02T00:00:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 63MB
2018-03-02T00:00:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 63MB
2018-03-02T00:00:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 63MB
2018-03-02T00:00:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 63MB
2018-03-02T00:00:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 64MB
2018-03-02T00:00:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 64MB
2018-03-02T00:00:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 64MB
2018-03-02T00:00:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 64MB
2018-03-02T00:00:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 64MB
2018-03-02T00:00:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 64MB
2018-03-02T00:00:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 64MB
2018-03-02T00:00:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 64MB
2018-03-02T00:00:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 65MB
2018-03-02T00:00:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 65MB
2018-03-02T00:00:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 65MB
2018-03-02T00:00:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 65MB
2018-03-02T00:00:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 65MB
2018-03-02T00:00:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 66MB
2018-03-02T00:00:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 66MB
2018-03-02T00:00:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 66MB
2018-03-02T00:00:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 66MB
2018-03-02T00:00:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 67MB
2018-03-02T00:00:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 67MB
2018-03-02T00:00:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 67MB
2018-03-02T00:00:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 68MB
2018-03-02T00:00:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 68MB
2018-03-02T00:00:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 68MB
2018-03-02T00:00:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 68MB
2018-03-02T00:00:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 68MB
2018-03-02T00:00:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 68MB
2018-03-02T00:00:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 68MB
2018-03-02T00:00:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 68MB
2018-03-02T00:00:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 68MB
2018-03-02T00:00:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 69MB
2018-03-02T00:00:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 69MB
2018-03-02T00:00:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 69MB
2018-03-02T00:00:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 69MB
2018-03-02T00:00:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 69MB
2018-03-02T00:00:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 69MB
2018-03-02T00:00:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 69MB
2018-03-02T00:00:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 69MB
2018-03-02T00:00:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 69MB
2018-03-02T00:00:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 69MB
2018-03-02T00:00:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 69MB
2018-03-02T00:00:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 69MB
2018-03-02T00:00:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 69MB
2018-03-02T00:00:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 69MB
2018-03-02T00:00:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 69MB
2018-03-02T00:00:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 69MB
2018-03-02T00:00:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 69MB
2018-03-02T00:00:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 69MB
2018-03-02T00:00:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 69MB
2018-03-02T00:00:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 70MB
2018-03-02T00:00:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 70MB
2018-03-02T00:00:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 70MB
2018-03-02T00:00:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 70MB
2018-03-02T00:00:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 70MB
2018-03-02T00:00:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 70MB
2018-03-02T00:00:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 70MB
2018-03-02T00:00:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 70MB
2018-03-02T00:00:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 71MB
2018-03-02T00:00:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 71MB
2018-03-02T00:00:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 72MB
2018-03-02T00:00:42+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 73MB
2018-03-02T00:00:42+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 74MB
2018-03-02T00:00:42+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 74MB
2018-03-02T00:00:42+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 75MB
2018-03-02T00:00:42+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 75MB
2018-03-02T00:00:42+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 76MB
2018-03-02T00:00:42+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 78MB
2018-03-02T00:00:43+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 78MB
2018-03-02T00:00:43+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 80MB
2018-03-02T00:00:43+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 80MB
2018-03-02T00:00:43+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 81MB
2018-03-02T00:00:43+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 81MB
2018-03-02T00:00:43+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 82MB
2018-03-02T00:00:44+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 82MB
2018-03-02T00:00:44+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 82MB
2018-03-02T00:00:44+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 83MB
2018-03-02T00:00:44+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 83MB
2018-03-02T00:00:44+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 83MB
2018-03-02T00:00:44+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 84MB
2018-03-02T00:00:44+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 84MB
2018-03-02T00:00:44+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 84MB
2018-03-02T00:00:44+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 84MB
2018-03-02T00:00:44+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 85MB
2018-03-02T00:00:44+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 85MB
2018-03-02T00:00:44+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 85MB
2018-03-02T00:00:44+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 86MB
2018-03-02T00:00:44+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 86MB
2018-03-02T00:00:44+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 86MB
2018-03-02T00:00:44+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 87MB
2018-03-02T00:00:44+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 87MB
2018-03-02T00:00:45+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 88MB
2018-03-02T00:00:45+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 88MB
2018-03-02T00:00:45+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 88MB
2018-03-02T00:00:45+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 88MB
2018-03-02T00:00:45+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 89MB
2018-03-02T00:00:45+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 89MB
2018-03-02T00:00:45+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 89MB
2018-03-02T00:00:45+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 89MB
2018-03-02T00:00:45+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 90MB
2018-03-02T00:00:45+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 90MB
2018-03-02T00:00:45+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 90MB
2018-03-02T00:00:45+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 91MB
2018-03-02T00:00:45+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 91MB
2018-03-02T00:00:45+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 91MB
2018-03-02T00:00:45+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 92MB
2018-03-02T00:00:45+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 92MB
2018-03-02T00:00:45+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 92MB
2018-03-02T00:00:46+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 93MB
2018-03-02T00:00:46+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 93MB
2018-03-02T00:00:46+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 86MB
2018-03-02T00:00:46+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 86MB
2018-03-02T00:00:46+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 87MB
2018-03-02T00:00:46+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 87MB
2018-03-02T00:00:46+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 87MB
2018-03-02T00:00:46+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 88MB
2018-03-02T00:00:46+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 88MB
2018-03-02T00:00:46+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 88MB
2018-03-02T00:00:46+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 88MB
2018-03-02T00:00:46+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 89MB
2018-03-02T00:00:46+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 89MB
2018-03-02T00:00:46+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 89MB
2018-03-02T00:00:46+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 90MB
2018-03-02T00:00:46+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 90MB
2018-03-02T00:00:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 90MB
2018-03-02T00:00:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 91MB
2018-03-02T00:00:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 91MB
2018-03-02T00:00:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 91MB
2018-03-02T00:00:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 92MB
2018-03-02T00:00:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 92MB
2018-03-02T00:00:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 92MB
2018-03-02T00:00:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 92MB
2018-03-02T00:00:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 93MB
2018-03-02T00:00:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 93MB
2018-03-02T00:00:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 93MB
2018-03-02T00:00:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 94MB
2018-03-02T00:00:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 94MB
2018-03-02T00:00:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 94MB
2018-03-02T00:00:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 95MB
2018-03-02T00:00:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 95MB
2018-03-02T00:00:47+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 95MB
2018-03-02T00:00:48+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 96MB
2018-03-02T00:00:48+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 96MB
2018-03-02T00:00:48+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 96MB
2018-03-02T00:00:48+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 96MB
2018-03-02T00:00:48+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 97MB
2018-03-02T00:00:48+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 97MB
2018-03-02T00:00:48+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 97MB
2018-03-02T00:00:48+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 98MB
2018-03-02T00:00:48+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 98MB
2018-03-02T00:00:48+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 98MB
2018-03-02T00:00:48+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 99MB
2018-03-02T00:00:48+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 99MB
2018-03-02T00:00:48+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 99MB
2018-03-02T00:00:48+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 100MB
2018-03-02T00:00:48+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 100MB
2018-03-02T00:00:48+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 100MB
2018-03-02T00:00:48+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 100MB
2018-03-02T00:00:48+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 101MB
2018-03-02T00:00:49+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 101MB
2018-03-02T00:00:49+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 101MB
2018-03-02T00:00:49+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 102MB
2018-03-02T00:00:49+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 102MB
2018-03-02T00:00:49+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 102MB
2018-03-02T00:00:49+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 103MB
2018-03-02T00:00:49+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 103MB
2018-03-02T00:00:49+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 103MB
2018-03-02T00:00:49+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 104MB
2018-03-02T00:00:49+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 104MB
2018-03-02T00:00:49+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 105MB
2018-03-02T00:00:49+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 105MB
2018-03-02T00:00:50+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 105MB
2018-03-02T00:00:50+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 105MB
2018-03-02T00:00:50+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 106MB
2018-03-02T00:00:50+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 106MB
2018-03-02T00:00:50+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 106MB
2018-03-02T00:00:50+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 106MB
2018-03-02T00:00:50+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 106MB
2018-03-02T00:00:50+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 106MB
2018-03-02T00:00:50+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 106MB
2018-03-02T00:00:50+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 107MB
2018-03-02T00:00:50+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 108MB
2018-03-02T00:00:50+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 108MB
2018-03-02T00:00:51+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 109MB
2018-03-02T00:00:51+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 110MB
2018-03-02T00:00:51+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 110MB
2018-03-02T00:00:51+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 110MB
2018-03-02T00:00:51+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 110MB
2018-03-02T00:00:51+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 110MB
2018-03-02T00:00:51+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 111MB
2018-03-02T00:00:51+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 112MB
2018-03-02T00:00:51+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 112MB
2018-03-02T00:00:52+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 113MB
2018-03-02T00:00:52+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 113MB
2018-03-02T00:00:52+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 113MB
2018-03-02T00:00:52+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 113MB
2018-03-02T00:00:52+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 114MB
2018-03-02T00:00:52+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 114MB
2018-03-02T00:00:52+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 114MB
2018-03-02T00:00:52+00:00 DEBUG (7): memoria in uso: 114MB
```

Now i'm sure there is no issue with the script inself.

So the problem should be in `/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 290`, as the error says:

```
        if (!imagefill($imageResourceTo, 0, 0, $color)) {
            throw new Exception("Failed to fill image background with color {$r} {$g} {$b}.");
        }
```

but this is a core file.

So, why does it use more memory when is called from cron observer instead of controller action?

Comment: Can you show the observer's code? It's obvious that it's using too much memory, but we can't tell why without seeing your observer.

Comment: @EthanYehuda i've edited the question. As you can see i use the same code becose i use controller to develope. The observer give memory issue in `Mage::getModel('amazon/feed')->getFeeds();` but the controller doesn't

Comment: how many feeds is the amazon model generating? Can you implement some kind of pagination if it's a lot of feeds?

Comment: @EthanYehuda check edit

Comment: @krybbio - just a quick though: what is the running duration of your script when executed manually from CLI? More than a minute (or ist it the 29 seconds as your `memoria in uso` log states?)? If so, is it possible that your fron is running every minute and `Mage::getModel('amazon/feed')->deleteAllFiles` is just deleting from a second execution while the first job is still running?

Comment: @ChristophFarnleitner the script is running once a day